# devenv always rebuilds my project, because a typescript file is newer than a pdb file

Tags: msbuild, devenv

I have a project with typescripts. devenv constantly rebuilding this project. Diagnostics output contains this line:

```
Project 'Benefits' is not up to date. Input file 'C:\abc\UI\BenefitsWeb\Scripts\Benefits\Modules\PPACA\ApprovalScreen.ts' is modified after output file 'C:\abc\UI\BenefitsWeb\bin\Dayforce.Web.Benefits.pdb'.
```

So, how do I resolve this issue? The aforementioned typescript file is truly newer than the PDB. But the PDB is not the output of the typescript compilation !!!

Here is how I compile my typescript files:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CompileDependsOn>
    $(CompileDependsOn);
    CompileTypeScript
  </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="GetInputs">
  ...
</Target>

<Target Name="GetOutputs">
  ...
</Target>

<Target Name="CompileTypeScript" DependsOnTargets="GetInputs;GetOutputs" Inputs="@(InputTypeScripts)" Outputs="@(OutputJavaScripts)">
  ...
</Target>
```

The project specifies the typescript files in the `TypeScriptCompile` item group, for instance:

```
<TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\Benefits\Modules\PPACA\CalendarSetup.ts" />
```

Of course, `@(OutputJavaScripts)` lists the expected `.js` files only. No PDB files there.

So how come devenv matches a typescript file with a PDB file? How do I fix it?

**EDIT 1**

I would like to clarify. It does not actually recompile the typescript or C# files (well for the first time it does recompile the typescript files, but only that). It starts the build, because typescript is newer than a PDB, but then it recognizes that no PDB dependency has actually changed. The same is true for the javascript files - they are all up-to-date. So nothing is actually rebuilt, but why to enter the build sequence in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with a `txt` file instead of a typescript file. I opened up the `csproj` file, found the section that declared the text files, and moved it above a section where it was declaring some project references. Basically, above any binary-type files. After reloading the project, MSBuild wouldn't build it unless a file in it had actually changed.

Comment: This is really interesting. Could you post a code snippet from the csproj file before and after your change?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a `js` file. Setting its `Build Action` to None, recompile, then back to `Content`, recompile solved the issue.