# VS 2012 .user file causes unnecessary builds

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, biztalk

There are a number of post in relation to Visual Studio building projects when not necessary. However, none seem to cover this particular issue.

I'm running Visual Studio 2012 Professional Update 4.

In my solution, I have a unit test project that has a project reference to a BizTalk Transforms project. This in-turn has a project reference to a BizTalk schemas project.

Every time I choose to run a unit test, the whole solution is built, even though no changes have been made.

The first line displayed in the build window is as follows:

> Input file
>   'C:\Workspaces\rbowman\Branches\Current-branchRB\WareHouse\FFF.Enterprise.WareHouse.Schemas\FFF.Enterprise.WareHouse.Schemas.btproj.user'
>   is modified after output file
>   'C:\Workspaces\rbowman\Branches\Current-branchRB\WareHouse\FFF.Enterprise.WareHouse.Schemas\bin\Release\FFF.Enterprise.WareHouse.Schemas.pdb'.

Note: it seems to be the **.user** file that's causing the rebuild.
Does anyone know how to prevent this? Strange but I only seem to be getting the problem with BizTalk proj files. I am seeing this behavior across multiple solutions but the problem file is always identified as a btproj.user.

This screencast illustrates the problem: [screencast link](http://biztalkers.com/video/build-before-test.mp4)

Comment: This happens to be normally if I have a file included in the project, which does not exist any more.

Comment: Do you mean the project of which the .user file is causing the rebuild (schemas.btproj in my case)? If the proj contained a file that it VS wasn't able to locate on disk I guess I'd see a "missing file" icon on the solution explorer but I don't have any in the entire solution

Comment: Set the readonly attribute on the file.  Either it leaves you in peace or something is going to say Bang! when it tries to update the file and you'll know more.

Comment: I liked your suggestion Hans. Unfortunately, setting the read-only flag on WareHouse.Schemas\FFF.Enterprise.WareHouse.Schemas.btproj.user made no difference - I get the same message and it builds even though no  changes made :(

Comment: What happens when you delete the .user file?

Comment: It gets re-created next time I run a test - so back to square one!

Comment: If I move the schemas.btproj.user file to a temp location, re-run the test then use Notepad++ for a compare with the newly created schemas.btproj.user I can see that they are exactly the same.

Comment: You shouln't just check the content, check the modified date?

Comment: I think that user file may be a red herring.  I also have a BizTalk solution and if I run all tests it also does a build before running the tests even if no changes have been made.  It seems to be standard behaviour.

Comment: Redo your .btproj file by hand - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853058/devenv-always-rebuilds-my-project-because-a-typescript-file-is-newer-than-a-pdb

Answer (score 1):

If you have just opened the solution, even if nothing has changed since the last time you built, if you click Run All, it will as per the description in Test Explorer do a build.

[image]

Comment: I get the same problem if I select Run All immediately after test runs completed i.e. I request a run for the second time. I've added a screen cast to better illustrate the problem: http://biztalkers.com/video/build-before-test.mp4

Comment: Yes, Run All always seems to cause it to recompile, a "feature" of Visual Studio 2012.  Running even selected unit test causes it to recompile as well, but it usually realizes that projects are up to date.   It did not used to do this in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You should **remove the *.user file** from your source control.

These files store user specific settings and should *never* be checked into source control.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. BizTalk projects insist on updating the btproj.user file on every build, resulting in a full rebuild every time.

I solved the problem with the following workaround: Set the ACL Write Flag on Deny. The build cannot update the file and the projects are only build when actually needed.

In my case build time went from 10 minutes to 2.